# Gradient of linear least squares problem as number of samples increases

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, regression, least-squares, gradient-descent

Consider the following linear least squares problem with the objective of minimizing the loss function $$L = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{x}_i - y_i)^2$$ where $N$ is the number of samples, $\vec{c}$ is a $d$-dimensional vector of unknowns while $(\vec{x}_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,N$ are the data.

I am very well aware that this is a convex optimization problem with a known analytical solution but I am making some numerical experiments and I'm trying to understand the results of my numerical experiments. Instead, I am solving this optimization problem with an optimizer such as adam. For the "optimal" solution provided to me by the optimizer, I compute $\|\nabla_{\vec{c}} L\|_2$ the norm of the gradient of the loss and check whether it is close to 0. This would then suggest that we're at the global minimum since this is a convex problem.

My observation is that for larger $N$ (more samples), then $\|\nabla_{\vec{c}} L\|_2$ is closer to 0. Is there a reason why this is the case? The only vague explanation I can think of is that the gradient of the loss can be thought of as an average because of the summation over $N$ terms divided by $N$. Thus, increasing $N$ gives a more accurate result.

However, I am not so sure about this intuition and was curious to hear other opinions.

Comment: For which initial vector of unknowns is this gradient computed? And how are additional data points generated?

Comment: Hi @HansEngler, i'm using a random initial condition generated as a realization of a zero-mean gaussian with differing variances. regarding the other question, it may be helpful to think of it this way: I have a large number of training samples (say 50000) and I can choose to subsample for the loss function, i.e. I can choose to use 1000 or all of the samples for the loss.

Comment: If the observations are all the same, say $x_i = x_0$ and $y_i = y_0$ for all $i$, then the gradient would be $\nabla L = 2 x_0 (x_0^Tc - y_0)$ for all $N$ and you would not see it becoming smaller as the number of samples $N$ becomes large.  So there are some unstated assumptions or special properties at work.

Comment: You should write in matrix form. Where's the descent?